# Android Drawable Round Corners Dyanamically

Tags: android, android-gridview, rounded-corners

I have a grid view with 3 columns and unlimited rows. What I hope is:

- Top left item, to have a top left rounded corner.
- Top right item to have a top right rounded corner.
- Bottom left item to have a bottom left rounded corner.
- Bottom right item to have a bottom right rounded corner.

I have thought that I could possibly create 4 xml files for each scenario, but I realize that I'd need to create not just 4. I'd need to create one more in case when there is only 1 item in the grid. 2 more in case there is only 1 row in the grid, one more for middle items, and who knows...

I am just wondering if there is a more elegant solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code may help you,

```
GradientDrawable drawable;
makeBackground(drawable, 5, R.color.black, 2, R.color.white);

private void makeBackground(GradientDrawable drawable, int radius, int backgroundColorResource, int borderWidth, int borderColorResource){
    drawable.setColor(getColor(getContext(), backgroundColorResource));
    drawable.setStroke(dpToPx(borderWidth), getColor(getContext(), borderColorResource));
    drawable.setCornerRadius(dpToPx(radius));
}

public static int dpToPx(int dp) {
    return (int) (dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}

public static int getColor(Context context, int res){
    return ContextCompat.getColor(context, res);
}
```

And for different values in different corner, you have to use [setCornerRadii](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html#setCornerRadii(float[])) instead of setCornerRadius.